# Can I change the 4KB size of the page in x86 processor? Why?

Tags: x86, operating-system, cpu, page-tables

In the processor x86 physical address space is divided into 4KB pages. Can the 4KB size of the page be changed?why?,please!

Answer (score 3):

Why? Well, by design. Modern x86 CPUs let operating systems construct their page tables such that page sizes can be larger than 4KB, e.g. they can be 2MB, 4MB and 1GB. The CPUID instruction tells you which are supported. The documentation tells you how to construct page tables with large pages. Read it.

Comment: worth mentioning that 4MB hugepages are only possible with legacy 32-bit 3-level page tables (10 bits per level), while 2MB and 1G hugepages are only possible with modern x86-64 page tables (9 bits per level).

Comment: @PeterCordes You've mentioned it, thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

x86 supports hugepages by making higher levels of the page table an actual entry instead of pointer to a page directory.

Other than that, no, the 4k page size is hard-wired into load/store execution units that have to detect 4k splits to decide if two TLB checks are needed for the 2 halves of a store uop.  (And if the halves might be physically discontiguous.)

There's simply no mechanism in the ISA that can select a different page size.  (Unlike in some, where you may have the choice of 4k, 8k, or 16k.)